# Expresiones regulares JS

Tags: javascript, php, validación

**Resumen**

Necesito validar un campo select con expresiones js, mi pregunta para ustedes es:

¿Como puedo decirle a mi cogido que me valide un campo select de la misma forma en la que valido mis demás inputs ?

**Porque Validar un Select**

Algunos Usuarios por afan, se les olvida seleccionar una opción y el select por defecto aroja "Seleccione..." cuando no deberia permitir eso, por eso quiero poder validar el select

De esta forma estoy validando mis inputs con las expreciones JS

```
const expresiones = {
    usuario: /^[0-9]{5,16}$/, //
    contraseña: /^[a-z,A-Z, 0-9 o _]{1,14}$/, // 7 a 14 numeros.
};
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="formulario__input" id="tipoUsuario" name="tipoUsuario">
    <option>Seleccione...</option>
    <option>Administrador</option>
    <option>Empleado</option>
</select>
```

¿Existe la posibilidad de validar el select usando expresiones regulares ?

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el `select` que quieres validar, con ejemplo de los valores que puede tener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas expresiones regulares, solo analizar el valor seleccionado. Así como lo tienes, puede ser:

```
if(inputUsuario.value == 'Seleccione...') {
    // Aquí el manejo de errores
}
```

Pero lo ideal es que asignes atributo `value` a cada opción:

```js
let tipoUsuario = document.querySelector('#tipoUsuario');
document.querySelector('#validar').addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(tipoUsuario.value == '') {
        console.log('Debes seleccionar un tipo de usuario.');
    } else {
        console.log('Has seleccionado: ' + tipoUsuario.value);
    }
});
```

```html
<select class="formulario__input" id="tipoUsuario" name="tipoUsuario">
    <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
    <option value="Administrador">Administrador</option>
    <option value="Empleado">Empleado</option>
</select>
<button id="validar">Validar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entiende que una expresión regular sirve para validar información introducida por el usuario, pero un SELECT en HTML, no permite al usuario introducir información como tal, sino que permite elegir entre varias opciones ya predefinidas. Por tanto, quizá no tenga mucho sentido validar un select con expresiones regulares ¿no?

Comment: si bro,pero me gustaría validad  el select ya que algunos usuarios por afan, se les olvida seleccionar una opción y el select por defecto aroja "Seleccione..." cuando no deberia permitir eso

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Entonces tienes dos opciones, poner un "required" en el select y obligar a que el usuario seleccione alguna de las opciones, o bien poner una opción por defecto, y si el usuario se olvida....iría con la opción por defecto.